# Turtlebot networking setup error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have a problem with networking setup. I followed this tut.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup

at the last step, on my workstation, I ran

```
rostopic pub -r10 /hello std_msgs/String "hello"
```

and when I ran

```
rostopic echo /hello
```

on my turtlebot laptop I got this:

```
WARNING: topic [/hello] does not appear to be published yet
```

according to the tut.

> The message "hello" begin printed
> about 10 times a second.

but that is not happening.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55145/turtlebot-networking-setup-error/) by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard way is to reboot both the workstation and the laptop, and then check:

echo $ROS_MASTER_URI

echo $ROS_HOSTNAME

In your workstation, the Master-URI should show the IP address of the TurtleBot laptop, but the hostname is the IP address (without http://) of the workstation.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0